# JQuery Radio Button Value Check

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to have the number of 'yes's' selected from a set of radio buttons shown in a hidden field.

I have a form with several sets of radio buttons.

The first radio set:

```
    <input type="radio" name="number_of_sets_to_count" id="number_of_sets_to_count_1" value="1">
    <input type="radio" name="number_of_sets_to_count" id="number_of_sets_to_count_2" value="2">
    <input type="radio" name="number_of_sets_to_count" id="number_of_sets_to_count_3" value="3">
    <input type="radio" name="number_of_sets_to_count" id="number_of_sets_to_count_4" value="4">
    <input type="radio" name="number_of_sets_to_count" id="number_of_sets_to_count_5" value="5">
```

Subject to the value selected above (ie 1,2,3,4,5) then to calculate the radio buttons selected yes from below radio buttons. ie if selected 2 in radio button above then the first two radio button sets need to check for yes. If 4 selected the the first 4 radio sets below need to be checked for yes values.

This is the next five radio sets

```
<input type="radio" name="set1" id="set1_no" value="no">
<input type="radio" name="set1" id="set1_yes" value="yes">

<input type="radio" name="set2" id="set2_no" value="no">
<input type="radio" name="set2" id="set2_yes" value="yes">

<input type="radio" name="set3" id="set3_no" value="no">
<input type="radio" name="set3" id="set3_yes" value="yes">

<input type="radio" name="set4" id="set4_no" value="no">
<input type="radio" name="set4" id="set4_yes" value="yes">

<input type="radio" name="set5" id="set5_no" value="no">
<input type="radio" name="set5" id="set5_yes" value="yes">


<input type="hidden" name="number_of_yes" value="">
```

Thanks to the community help I have this JQuery code that calculates the number of yes's in the form and puts the number into the hidden text box 'number_of_yes' on submit.

```
<script type="text/javaScript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#yourFormsId").submit(function() {
         $('input[name="number_of_yes"]').val(
            $('input:checked[type="radio"][value="yes"]').length); 
  });
});
</script>
```

But, this checks for all yes's selected and I need this limited to the first, second, third, fourth or fifth radio sets (ie set1, set2, set3, set4, set5) depending on what is selected from the number_of_sets_to_count radio button (ie 1,2,3,4,5).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

$("input[name=number_of_sets_to_count]").click(function(){

  var radioBtns = $("input[id^='set']");

  //First set all the radio buttons to No
  radioBtns.filter("[value='no']").attr("checked", true);

  //Now set only the required radio buttons to yes
  radioBtns.filter("[value='yes']:lt("+parseInt($(this).val())+")").attr("checked", true);


});
  $("#yourFormsId").submit(function() {

      $('input[name="number_of_yes"]').val($('input:checked[type="radio"][value="yes"]').length); 
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you alert this.value in the click handler?

Comment: :( Still not working, it still checks all radio buttons for yes... Hard

Comment: Please check my edited answer now it works fine. I have put up a fiddle also here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/5Zusr/4/)

Comment: Just checked.. :( still not working, checked fiddle, what needs to happen is that if number_of_sets_to_count is say 3 the only set1, set2 and set3 need to be checked for yes, but al the moment they all are.. For example selected number_of_sets_to_count to 2 but made all of the yes, and the it showed all as yes, not just the two? Is that clear?

Comment: In the fiddle I provided it is working as you expect take a look at it carefully.

Comment: There was one small change which I made in the fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/5Zusr/5/) and also edited the answer, please take a look.

Comment: :( Still not working? Can you put a hidden field into the fiddle to show the number.. My version is still checking all Yes, if number_of_sets_to_count is say, 3, then only the first 3 sets of radio buttons checked and included for yes..

Comment: Take a look now I have put a div in which it will show the number of yes when you click on any top radio buttons. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/5Zusr/6/) http://jsfiddle.net/5Zusr/6/

Comment: Hi, sorry I got sidetracked... Excellent work.. thank you and sorry for slow reply.. Great work